# How to draw a flying balloon by cocos2d-js

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm new in cocos2d-js and I would like to make a simple game as below

on screen(web, android or ios) have some balloons(bubble) flying from bottom to top(randomly appear and fly). When I touched to one of them, then it will explosion(bum with sound I configured)

Everyone who can help me to resolve it and the source code is strongly welcome.

Thanks & best regards.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading through the "Parkour Game Tutorials of Cocos2d-JS v3.x": http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Getting_Started_Cocos2d-JS.

Everything needed for your task is covered in this article.

Comment: @hai-nguyen: If you find my comment usefule, please accept it as answer.